# Ubuntu broken need to recover mysql db

Tags: linux, mysql-5.6, ubuntu, backup, disaster-recovery

With a recent Ubuntu upgrade it has broken my system. I now only have access to the filesystem through a live CD. I had a MySQL database on the system with many objects and views I would hate to lose. Can I recover this somehow? I don't care about the data; I just need the DDL structure of everything.

Comment: And there, folks, is the reason we have backups! Can you use a USB drive to copy the files through the live CD?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I would like to do except once I chroot into the filesystem i  not sure what to do to recover the schema (Which files/folders, commands to backup and later restore)

Comment: First thing I would try is to copy over the data files and then put them under a new install of the same version of MySQL as the broken one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to recover by filetype, please note the following structure in MySql database file system:

> A MySQL table is the combination of three files:
>
> - The FRM file is the table definition.
> - The MYD file is where the actual data is stored.
> - The MYI file is where the indexes created on the table are stored.

**Source:**
[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files

What this does not provide are the views. I did search a while and could not find where they are.

Same source tells how to restore the database from files. Copy them to  /var/lib/mysql/ on machine that has same version of Mysql installed.

That is needed to get more complex structures out of the files, and if the file sizes don't limit you, it would be also the most convenient way to do this.

Note you should close the server from running before changes in filesystem.